# Could not find method suites() for arguments [src/test/resources/testSuite.xml] on project

Tags: java, gradle, testng

I have created a project in gradle with testng framework, how to execute test-suite in testng  using gradle, please help here is my build.gradle

```
build.gradle   

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
version = '1.0'
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Quickstart',
                   'Implementation-Version': version
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.2'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
}

test {
    systemProperties 'property': 'value'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
test {
    useTestNG() {
        suites 'src/test/resources/testng.xml'
    }
}
```

Comment: You will have to dig deeper because it is how testng is using tesng (and it is working) ;) https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/build.gradle#L116-L119